# To check a list and populate the value accordingly

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string list with values. I need to assign a value to a list based on the particular index of the string. Below is my code for the same.

```
var fruits = new string[] { "Color", "Price", "Shape ", "Nutrients" };

var fruitDetails = db.Fruits.Where(f => f.FruitId == 5).Select(f => new FruitModel{Id = f.FruitId,Category=f.Category, Color = f.FruitColor, Price=f.FruitPrice, Shape = f.FruitShape, Nutrients = f.FruitNutrients}).FirstOrDefault();
```

Now I need to populate a list using the results obtained from the Linq query based on the list of fruits.

```
foreach (var item in fruits )
{
    var fruitData = new fruitData ();
    fruitData.Category= fruitDetails .Category;
    fruitData.Description= ; //This has to be the value of Color if item is color,value of price if item is price and so on...

    fruitList.Add(fruitData);
}
```

So based on what the loop value is corresponding value needs to be populated. I do not want to be using Reflection. Is there an alternate method?

Comment: You probably should use a `dictionary<k,v>` in that case

Comment: Your array of strings is not a series of fruits. It should really be named something different. Perhaps `fruitPropertiesToExtract` or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you use a `switch` statement like

```
  switch (item)
  {
      case "Color":
          fruitData.Description = fruitDetails.Color; 
          break;
      case "Price":
          fruitData.Description = fruitDetails.Price;
          break;
      case "Nutrient":
          fruitData.Description = fruitDetails.Nutrient;
          break;
      default:              
          break;
  }
```

Comment: Totally missed that I could use Switch. Will accept the answer once I implement it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding a property to `FruitModel` that returns the description based on the instance's Category, and that can use a static `Dictionary` to map categories to accessor functions:

```
public class FruitModel {
    public int Id;
    public string Category;
    public string Color;
    public double Price;
    public string Shape;
    public string Nutrients;

    static Dictionary<string, Func<FruitModel, string>> catmap = new Dictionary<string, Func<FruitModel, string>> {
        { "Color", fm => fm.Color },
        { "Price", fm => fm.Price.ToString() },
        { "Shape", fm => fm.Shape },
        { "Nutrients", fm => fm.Nutrients },
    };

    public string Description {
        get => catmap[Category](this);
    }
    public static List<string> FruitDetailCategories {
        get => catmap.Keys.ToList();
    }
}
```

You can also create a static property to return the detail categories rather than put the list somewhere else.

(Obviously you could use the switch instead of the `Dictionary` if preferred in the property body, but it doesn't lend itself to providing the detail categories.)

Now you can build your list easily:

```
var fruitList = new List<FruitData>();
foreach (var fruit in fruitDetails) {
    var fd = new FruitData();
    fd.Category = fruit.Category;
    fd.Description = fruit.Description;
    fruitList.Add(fd);
}
```